# Drawable resources read from a xml document

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

I'm using an xml document on resources/raw in order to fill a ListView, here's the code:

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data)));
        XmlPullParser p = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
        p.setInput(br);
        int tipoevento = p.next();
        while (tipoevento != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            switch (tipoevento) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (p.getAttributeValue(null,"id") != null) {
                        items.add(
                                new Item(
                                        Integer.parseInt(p.getAttributeValue(null, "id")),
                                        p.getAttributeValue(null, "name"),
                                        p.getAttributeValue(null, "url")));
                    }
                    break;
                default:break;
            }
            tipoevento=p.next();
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());}
```

And, when I run it, I get the following error: Error:﹕ Invalid int: "R.drawable.following".
I put the resources id in the xml this way and I know the error is in the parse but I didn't know how to do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<filmList>
<film name="Following" id="R.drawable.following" url="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0154506/"/>
<film name="Memento" id="R.drawable.memento" url="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0209144/"/>
<film name="Batman Begins" id="R.drawable.batman_begins" url="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0372784/"/>
<film name="The Prestige" id="R.drawable.the_prestige" url="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0482571/"/>
<film name="The Dark Knight" id="R.drawable.the_dark_knight" url="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/"/>
<film name="Inception" id="R.drawable.inception" url="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/"/>
<film name="The Dark Knight Rises" id="R.drawable.the_dark_knight_rises" url="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1345836/"/>
</filmList>
```

Comment: `"R.drawable.following"` is a string and cannot be parsed as an integer. You can't refer to resources this way in XML; the `R.type.entry` syntax is for use in Java code, not XML.

Comment: then how can I refer the resources and later use them in java?

Comment: You can try providing just the drawable name (e.g. `id="following"`), then use `Resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", "your.package.name")` to find the actual integer id that you would use in java. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)